# SSAS Tabular / Dax: Show sum of a measure on parent level in Parent-Child-hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a SSAS tabular model with a parent-child hierarchy and around 10 measures within different display folders. If I open up the parent level of the hierarchy the measures of the parent level are not shown any more. Only the children elements are showing those measures. Is there any option to show also the measures on parent level?  (In the image I would expect the sum of the child elements in the yellow marked row.) Any help is much appreciated.

[image: sample]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In a new Power BI workbook hit the "Enter Data" button and manually type in a few rows and columns.  Then go to Transform Data and open the Advanced Editor for that query.  Cut and paste the query definition into your question.  Then add the measure definition and a screenshot of the visual that you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a **Matrix** visual in Power BI, go into formatting and turn on **Row subtotals**.

[image: Row subtotals]